# Ckfinder 3 открывает главную страницу сайта, Yii1

Tags: php, yii, ckeditor

Есть проблемка с ckfinder, при нажатий на кнопку "Выбор на сервере" открывается новая вкладка (пример ссылки :"/assets/4dsf46ds/ckfinder/ckfinder.html"), но там открывается главная страница моего сайта. Локально все открывает. Искал в инете много, но ничего не нашел (мб не так искал). Фрэймворк yii1.